# Wrongly used tag: [windows-scheduler]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-disambiguation

[windows-scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-scheduler) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-scheduler/info)

At first glance, it refers to Windows **Task** Scheduler, with a blatantly wrong tag wiki. I was going to edit the wiki to reflect the "correct meaning". Then I stopped and abandoned the draft. Something must have been wrong. The tag wiki clearly refers to **priority scheduling**, not "routine tasks".

Checking the question list, it seems 90%+ question are using this tag for "Windows Task Scheduler", while a *really* small portion are talking about process priorities.

Given that there are only 82 questions tagged this, and only ***3/50*** in the first page are "correct uses" (i.e. process priority), shall we "magically transform" this tag into "Windows Task Scheduler" (and probably find another tag for its original intention/usage)?

---

This was [completed](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) in December 2019.

Comment: When you say 3/50, do you mean 6% of the 82 or do you mean you looked at 50 questions of the 82? It feels weird to talk about parts out of 50 when there's 82 of them.

Comment: @DavyM Clarified.

Comment: Looking at all the downvotes, probably "no retag request".

Answer (score 4):

Of all questions in that tag, [60](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows-scheduler%5D+%22Task+Scheduler%22) contain the text *"Task Scheduler"*

The appropriate response (imo) would be to retag the wrongly questions to the appropriate tag, and perhaps change the tag name to something less ambiguous (such as *windows-system-scheduler*). The appropriate meta tag for such a request is [tag-disambiguation](/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation)

Note, however, that there are two tags about Windows Task Scheduler: [schtasks.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schtasks.exe) with 110 questions, and [schtasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schtasks) with 73 questions (15 overlapping). These tags should likely be merged before retagging to one of these.

Comment: I didn't even know [meta-tag:tag-disambiguation] exists!

Comment: I suggest `windows-thread-scheduling` as the improved name, since "system scheduler" is still ambiguous